# Jquery -How to display text lookup for a stored numeric value when retrieving to display to the user

Tags: jquery, local-storage, each

First -I am a total newbie and trying to work on someone elses code, so hopefully I will provide all the information necessary.

My jquery mobile application stores search parameters into local storage as numeric representation of the text because of the interface to the back-end.  The search parameters have three questions that have 6 to 15 different options.  A customer can save a search in their favorites.  I need to convert the numbers into text to make it user friendly for the customer.
I know how to convert the responses that have less than two responses, but I don't know how to do it for three or more.

Almost all the content is dynamically generated via Ajax, so a jsFiddle is impossible (at least for me ;-).

When a search result is returned (think of searching for a cruise), the following information is stored in local storage via this command:

```
localStorage.search = JSON.stringify(searchParams);
```

It is stored as follows:

> {"departuredate":"","returndate":"","region":"62224","price":"4","duration":"5"}

Then if a customer wants to save the search as a 'favorite', it is stored with the following command:

```
localStorage.favorites = JSON.stringify(favorites);
```

Example of a favorite search stored in localStorage:

> {"search":{"62224:4:5::":{"searchID":"62224:4","searchinfo":{"departuredate":"","returndate":"","region":"62224","price":"4","duration":"5"}}}}

Here is my code for retrieving the saved searches:

```
>     $.each(searches, function(idx, searchFav){
>     var search = searchFav.searchinfo;
>     var newSearchFav = template.clone().appendTo(disp);
>     newSearchFav.attr('id', idx);
>     $('#region', newSearchFav).html(search.region);
>     $('#price', newSearchFav).html(search.price);
>     $('#duration', newSearchFav).html(search.duration);
>     $('#depart', newSearchFav).html((search.departuredate);
>     $('#return', newSearchFav).append((search.returndate);
```

Using the example saved search in localStorage above, the above code displays on the html pages as follows:

- region id: 62224
- price id: 4
- duration id: 5
- depart id:
- return id:

I want duration to appear as "14+ Nights" and not as "5" based on the following look-up table:

- 0 = "Any Nights!"
- 1 = "1-3 Nights"
- 2 = "4-6 Nights"
- 3 = "7-9 Nights"
- 4 = "10-13 Nights"
- 5 = "14+ Nights"

If I had only two responses, I could put in the following (as an example)

```
 search.duration = ((search.duration > 4) ? "14+ Nights" : "Any");
$('#duration', newSearchFav).html(search.duration);
```

and any value 4 or below would display "Any". But I don't know how to do more than two responses.

Comment: What is "local storage", javascript variables, cookie ...?

Comment: And what does the template's HTML look like?

Comment: Let me see if I can put it into a jsfiddle

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do a jsfiddle with the dynamic content retrieved via AJAX and localStorage, so I updated the problem with more detail.  I can probably upload to a webserver and post a URL if necessary.  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the following:

```
search.duration = (search.duration > 4) ? "14+ Nights" : (search.duration == 4) ? "10-13 Nights" : (search.duration == 3) ? "7-9 Nights" : (search.duration == 2) ? "4-6 Nights" : (search.duration == 1) ? "1-3 Nights" : "Any Duration";
```